# Android - Error when i'm trying to apply a custom layout on Navigation Drawers

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to apply a custom layout for my navigation drawer, i have created a custom adapter which extends of baseAdapter, but i'm always getting the same error, i can't fix it. Please help me, I'm really stuck and i need it.

Log error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cervezaya.cervezaya, PID: 21390
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cervezaya.cervezaya/com.cervezaya.cervezaya.Inicio}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
        at com.cervezaya.cervezaya.Inicio.onCreate(Inicio.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment NavigationDrawerFragment{42304e20} not attached to Activity
        at android.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:767)
        at android.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:789)
        at com.cervezaya.cervezaya.NavigationDrawerFragment.<init>(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:40)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:590)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4795)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
            at com.cervezaya.cervezaya.Inicio.onCreate(Inicio.java:26)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class Inicio extends Activity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {


private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);
    configureNavigationDrawer();
}



@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    if (position == 0){

            //Llamada a sí mismo

    }else{
            if (position == 1){

                Intent intentFavoritos = new Intent(Inicio.this, Favoritos.class);
                startActivity(intentFavoritos);

            }else{
                if (position == 2){

                    Intent intentHistorial = new Intent(Inicio.this, Historial.class);
                    startActivity(intentHistorial);

                }else{

                    Intent intentFeedback = new Intent(Inicio.this, Feedback.class);
                    startActivity(intentFeedback);
                }
            }

        }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_inicio, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_map) {
        Intent intenVistaMapa = new Intent(Inicio.this, VistaMapa.class);
        startActivity(intenVistaMapa);
        return true;
    }else{

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void configureNavigationDrawer(){

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}



}
```

NavigationDrawerFragment.class

```
  public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private String[] sidebar_items = {getString(R.string.title_drawer1), getString(R.string.title_drawer2), getString(R.string.title_drawer3), getString(R.string.title_drawer4)};
    private int[] sidebar_images_on = {R.drawable.inicio_on, R.drawable.favoritos_on, R.drawable.historial_on, R.drawable.enviar_opinion_on};
    //private int[] sidebar_images_off = {R.drawable.inicio_off, R.drawable.favoritos_off, R.drawable.historial_off, R.drawable.enviar_opinion_off};

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.sidebar, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });


        //the problem is when I try to apply the adapter

        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new SidebarAdapter(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),sidebar_items,sidebar_images_on ));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;


    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {

                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };


        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return getActivity().getActionBar();
    }

    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}
    }
```

SidebarAdapter.class

```
    public class SidebarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] elements;
    int[] images;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageView icon;
    TextView title;

    SidebarAdapter(Context context, String[] elements, int[] images){

        this.context=context;
        this.elements = elements;
        this.images = images;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return elements.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return elements[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View row = null;

        if(view == null){

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sidebar_items,viewGroup,false);

            icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.sidebar_icon);
            title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sidebar_text);

        }else{
            row = view;
        }

        icon.setImageResource(images[i]);
        title.setText(elements[i]);

        return row;
    }
}
```

activity_inicio.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".Login">

    <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/Relative_layout_inicio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Inicio_activity"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>




    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.cervezaya.cervezaya.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/sidebar" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

sidebar.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:background="#F7F7F7" tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

sidebar_items.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sidebar_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/inicio_on"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Inicio"
        android:id="@+id/sidebar_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sidebar_icon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sidebar_icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sidebar_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to fetch resources in the initializer of your fragment's sidebar_items array:

```
private String[] sidebar_items = {
    getString(R.string.title_drawer1), getString(R.string.title_drawer2), 
    getString(R.string.title_drawer3), getString(R.string.title_drawer4)};
```

The call to getString requires that the Fragment is already attached to an Activity. However, that doesn't happen until later.

You have a two options:

1. Convert sidebar_items into an int array, like sidebar_images_on, and
   call getString when you access the array.
2. Override onAttach(Activity) in your Fragment, and initialize sidebar_items
   there.